# Copy and paste the last 5 active cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the last 5 active cells in column D. Everyday we add a new column and the summary data needs to reflect this.

I need to copy these last five figures and paste them across in a row in a different worksheet.

I have been able to select each of the individual cells and copy them, but I'm struggling at pasting them in a different worksheet.

```
Range("D1000").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(-4,0)
```

I cannot highlight all five of the figures at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is dynamic in respect of last row ( calculate the last row of column D instead of using fix value - 1000) You could modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Change worksheet name if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of co;lumn D
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("D" & LastRow - 4 & ":D" & LastRow).Copy
        .Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: I'm now struggling to paste the highlighted column as a row. I have used

Comment: I have used Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ =False, Transpose:=True

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refer to the workbook which includes the code. If you want to refer in different workbook you should replace `ThisWorkbook` with `Workbooks("Name")`